# Magento 1 - How to redirect on previous page after login

Tags: authentication, magento, magento-1.9

I'm using Magento 1.9.* and I would like to redirect previous page after user login successfully login.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you come across any errors? Do you have anything to share? We can't help you based on a "I want this" type statement

Comment: Hi @m_callens, I have try to redirect on home page, but i need to redirect last page, for example user on cart page and open login page then login successfully then it redirect cart page not my account page.  Any idea what can i do?? can i manage with session??? please let me know if you understand and you have any idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found one solution,

for that follow the below steps 
Open `header.phtml` add this code at top of the file

```
if(!Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {
 $loginback=$this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
 $check=strstr($loginback, 'customer/account/login');
 if(!strlen($check)){
 Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setLoginBackUrl($loginback);
 }
}
```

override `/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers` to you local or custom module and add this function

```
protected function _loginPostRedirect()
{
    $session = $this->_getSession();

    $backUrlcustom=Mage::getSingleton('core/session')
    ->getLoginBackUrl();

    if(isset($backUrlcustom) && $backUrlcustom !=""){
          $session->setBeforeAuthUrl($backUrlcustom);
    }
    $this->_redirectUrl($session->getBeforeAuthUrl(true));
}
```

It's work for me.

Answer (score 1):

For this, the config setting needs to be `System -> Configuration -> CUSTOMERS -> Customer Configuration -> Login Options Set: Redirect Customers to Account Dashboard after Loggin in = No`.

But there is some more work for this to do. Please check the core controller `/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php` class `_loginPostRedirect` method you mentioned, check the `if ($referer) {` section. That is the point you need to go there.

So for this, you don't need to change anything in any class.
Just add below codes in you login form phtml within `<form>` tag.

```
<?php if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(
        Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_STARTUP_REDIRECT_TO_DASHBOARD
    )) { ?>
    <input name="referer" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode(Mage::getBaseUrl()); ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

Example of a login form,

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post">
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
<?php if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(
        Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_STARTUP_REDIRECT_TO_DASHBOARD
    )) { ?>
    <input name="referer" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode(Mage::getBaseUrl()); ?>" />
<?php } ?>
<div class="block-content">
    <label for="mini-login"><?php echo $this->__('Email address:') ?></label><input type="text" name="login[username]" id="mini-login" class="input-text" />
    <label for="mini-password"><?php echo $this->__('Password:') ?></label><input type="password" name="login[password]" id="mini-password" class="input-text" />
    <div class="mini-actions">
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getForgotPasswordUrl() ?>" class="f-left"><?php echo $this->__('Forgot Your Password?') ?></a>
        <button type="submit" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Log in') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In above example, the customer will goes to the value of the referer field: `<input name="referer" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode(Mage::getBaseUrl()); ?>" />`

**So if need to change this value to the current page URL or Previous page so the user comes back to this page. Please change this as per your requirement `Mage::getBaseUrl()`**

Say, if you are using it on a mini login form like dropdown, you need to use current URL of the page ie. `Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()`.

If you are in login page, in that case you need to use the previous url ie. `HTTP_REFERER` ie `Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer()` of the login page.

```
<?php if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(
        Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::XML_PATH_CUSTOMER_STARTUP_REDIRECT_TO_DASHBOARD
    )) { ?>
    <input name="referer" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer()); ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: this solution is the quickest and easiest way as of Aug 2018

Answer (score 0):

The solutions of Dhrumin and Sandipan work, but I did not want to overwrite core classes and I needed a solution for login and redirect. For magento 1.9.x it seems that the only thing we have todo is to set the variable "BeforeAuthUrl" of the consumer session. Both the login and register method redirect to this url (if it exists). I put this code snippet in my header.phtml:

```
if (!Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {
$loginback = $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
$checkLogin = strstr($loginback, 'customer/account/login');
$checkRegister = strstr($loginback, 'customer/account/create');
if (!strlen($checkLogin) && !strlen($checkRegister) ) {
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl($loginback);
 }
}
```